# What causes MarshallingError when removing a server with reconfig command in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to remove one of the five servers using the `reconfig` command but get `KeeperErrorCode = MarshallingError`.

Here's the cluster information and the error message:

```
[zk: [ClientIP](CONNECTED) 2] get /zookeeper/config
server.0=[ip0]:port1:port2:participant
server.1=[ip1]:port1:port2:participant
server.2=[ip2]:port1:port2:participant
server.3=[ip3]:port1:port2:participant
server.4=[ip4]:port1:port2:participant
version=200000000
[zk: [ClientIP](CONNECTED) 3] reconfig -remove server.2=[ip2]:port1:port2:participant
KeeperErrorCode = MarshallingError
```

I'm not sure why this error occurred and how to solve it. How can I remove one of the servers?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

1. You don't need to specify server IPs on remove:

   reconfig [-s] [-v version] [[-file path] | [-members serverID=host:port1:port2;port3[,...]*]] | [-add serverId=host:port1:port2;port3[,...]]* [-remove serverId[,...]*]
2. only set the serverId

Example of good command:

```
[shahar.l]#  /opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 reconfig -remove 5
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
Committed new configuration:
server.4=IP:2888:3888:participant;0.0.0.0:2181
server.6=IP:2888:3888:participant;0.0.0.0:2181
server.7=IP:2888:3888:participant;0.0.0.0:2181
version=1700007e9d
```